# Start sync gateway service when system restarts

Tags: ubuntu, service, startup, couchbase-sync-gateway

I start the sync gateway server from command line like this:

```
$ ./sync_gateway_service_install.sh
```

But I have to do this every time I reboot the server. Is there any way to make this script run at server start up?
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
The problem was Sync Gateway service was going to start before Couchbase Server was started. To solve this issue edit the couchbase_init.d file as following:

`$ nano /opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase_init.d`

look for `start() {` section and change it from this:

```
    errcode=$?
    return $errcode
```

to this:

```
   errcode=$?
   sleep 20
   initctl emit couchbase-server-started
   return $errcode
```

Then edit the sync-gateway.conf file

```
$ nano /etc/init/sync_gateway.conf
```

and change this line:

```
    start on runlevel [2345]
```

to this:

```
    start on runlevel [2345] and couchbase-server-started
```

That will start the sync-gateway service after Couchbase server is started.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Very helpful.